# Custom Font. Keeping the font width same

Tags: iphone

I am trying to draw  a string using quartz 2d.

What i am doing is, i am drawing each letter of the string individually, because each letter has special attributes associated with it, by taking each letter into a new string.

The string gets printed, but the space between the letters is not uniform. It looks very ugly to read . 
I read someting about using custom fonts. But i have no Idea, if I can do it!! 
my code is here.

```
- (void) drawRect : (CGRect)rect{
  NSString *string=@"My Name Is Adam";
  float j=0;
  const char *charStr=[string cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 

  for(int i=0;i<strlen(charStr);i++)


   {
      NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",charStr[i]];
      const char *s=[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"%s",s);   

      CGContextRef context=[self getMeContextRef];
      CGContextSetTextMatrix (context,CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0)) ;
      CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
     //CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 10);



       CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 0,0,200, 1); 
       CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context,kCGTextFill);
       CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 80+j,80,s,1);
       j=j+15;

}

}
```

In the output 'My Name is Adam' gets printed but the space between the letters is not uniform.!! is there any way to make the space uniform!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general each character has a different advance, so you should account for it when drawing your text. Instead of using `j`, do the following:

```
// ...
CGContextSetTextPosition(initX,initY);
for(...){
    // ...
    CGPoint pos = CGContextGetTextPosition(context);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(pos.x+extraSpace,pos.y);
    CGContextShowText(context,s,1);
    // ...
}
```

set `extraSpacing` to zero to get the font's default spacing.

Also, I'm not sure what attributes you're using, but why don't you just use `NSAttributedString` (or `CF*`)?

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is not yet available on the iPhone.

Comment: huh, I didn't notice! `CFAttributedString` is there, but there's no API to handle its drawing... Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-proportional/fixed width font such as Monaco or Courier.  Let me know the results.

Comment: yeah Courier worked. But Monaco is not working. can u tell me name of other non-proportion/fixed fonts . Coz Courier is too simple and Monaco is not showing anyting

Comment: You could try drawing each character seperately, moving the x position by a fixed amount.