# The image is not displayed correctly in NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, textkit

I want use the object - `NSTextField` to display an image. But the result isn't correct.

the image size is 32x32.

my code like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

var text: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    text = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)))
    text.backgroundColor = .clear
    text.isBordered = true
    text.isEditable = false

    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "Group_8"))
    attachment.bounds = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: (attachment.image?.size)!)

    let string = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

    text.attributedStringValue = string

    view.addSubview(text)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The final displayed like this:

[image]

Why white blank areas appear？

Comment: It would look weird if the text touches the border. `NSImageView` is more suitable for displaying images.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Willeke that you should be using an NSImageView, what you're seeing is the NSTextField's "bezel".

You can disable it by adding

```
text.isBezeled = false
```

to your code.

Comment: `NSTextView` or `NSTextField`? Will the border still be visible?

Comment: NSTextField: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399435-isbezeled. Yes, the border will still be visible, though it's very close in colour to the background of your image, so it will be hard to see.

Comment: The documentation of `isBezeled` says "if NO, the receiver does not draw a border.". `isBezeled` must be set before `isBordered`.

Comment: You're correct. There is no border if the bezel is disabled - an artifact of the image I was using.

Comment: I find the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038008/1039703, thank you both

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property : `lineFragmentPadding = 0` . the white padding will disappear.

Beacuse the reason is that :

> The padding appears at the beginning and end of the line fragment
>   rectangles. The layout manager uses this value to determine the layout
>   width. The default value of this property is 5.0.